# Mysql selecting values based on other column value

Tags: mysql

Hi i have a table like so it includes a user id, date, amount and active flag

| id | date | amount | active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2017-07-12 | 10 | 1 |
| 1001 | 2017-07-12 | 5 | 0 |
| 1001 | 2017-07-12 | 12 | 0 |
| 1001 | 2017-05-05 | 5 | 0 |
| 1001 | 2017-06-01 | 11 | 0 |

my requirement is to get the total amount for this particular user for the whole day that he was active, so since the user was active on the date of '2017-07-12' i should be able to get all the amount for that particular date so my amount for this particular user would be 27.

What would be a right query to perform this action in mysql by looking at the active flag and how would i go about to do it?

Comment: Hi i think i was not clear enough so the user 1001 has made 5 payments in total and he was active for the date of 2017-07-12 so he was in an active state for that whole day so when i calculate the amount although only one record has active as 1 i will have to calculate the amount for the whole day he was active to get the correct result therefore since he was active on the date '2017-07-12' we will have to add up all the 3 records with the same date thus the amount 10 + 5 + 12 = 27.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use an aggregation approach here:

```sql
SELECT id, SUM(amount) AS total_amount
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM yourTable t1
    WHERE active = 1 OR
          EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM yourTable t2
                  WHERE t2.date = t1.date AND
                        t2.active = 1)
) t
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```

### Demo

Comment: HI but wouldn't this just give me the value as 10 since were only adding up the values when active is 1, but my need is that i want the sum of all amounts for the date the user was active on so since this user was active on '2017-07-12' the total amount would be 27 = 10 + 5 + 12 adding up all the amounts for that particular date.

Comment: @SouravRS Tricky one...check the updated answer for one approach.

Answer (score 0):

Either

```sql
SELECT id, `date`, SUM(amount) amount
FROM table
GROUP BY 1, 2
HAVING SUM(active)
```

or

```sql
SELECT id, `date`, SUM(amount) * (SUM(active) > 0) amount
FROM table
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

depends on desired output (does "non-active" dates must be skipped at all, or they'd be returned with zero amount).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
select tbl.id,
       tbl.`date`,
       sum(amount) as tot_date_amount
from tbl
inner join (select `date`
            from tbl 
            where active = 1
            ) as t2 on tbl.`date`=t2.`date`
group by id,`date`;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c173dcc9a72490146ff7c094a10b08b6

The subquery  will select only the dates where active = 1 .Using inner join will return only the sum for the active = 1 dates

Comment: sorry i just saw that i've made a typo on the dates and have added 2017-02-12 for one of the dates sorry for any incovenience caused and your observation for the amount of 15 is indeed correct

Comment: Yes it did indeed get me the result i was looking for